# sed or awk to capture part of url

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I am not very experienced with regular expressions and sed/awk scripting.

I have urls that are similar to the following torrent url:

```
http://torcache.net/torrent/D7249CD9AF321C8578B3A7007ABBDD63B0475EEB.torrent?title=[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent
```

I would like to have **sed** or **awk** script extract the text after the title i.e
from the example above just get:

**[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove everything before the title=: `sed 's/.*title=//'`

```
$ echo "http://torcache.net/torrent/D7249CD9AF321C8578B3A7007ABBDD63B0475EEB.torrent?title=[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent" | sed 's/.*title=//'
[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach with `awk`: use the `=` as the field separator:

```
awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

Thus:

```
echo "http://torcache.net/torrent/D7249CD9AF321C8578B3A7007ABBDD63B0475EEB.torrent?title=[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent" | awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say:

```
s='http://torcache.net/torrent/D7249CD9AF321C8578B3A7007ABBDD63B0475EEB.torrent?title=[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent'
```

**Pure BASH solution:**

```
echo "${s/*title=}"
[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent
```

**OR using `grep -P`:**

```
echo "$s"|grep -oP 'title=\K.*'
[kickass.to]against.the.ropes.by.carly.fall.epub.torrent
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `sed` (no need to mention `title` in the regexp in your example) :

```
 sed 's/.*=//'
```

An another solution exists with `cut`, another standard unix tool :

```
 cut -d= -f2
```